# How to stop receiving onTouchEvents for a gesture after returning true the first time

Tags: android

I know that for an Android view, if I return `true` to `onTouchEvent`, then it means that you want to continue receiving events for the current gesture. If you return `false` it should not process more events for the current gesture

However I'd like to try to detect whether a gesture is a click or a hold/drag event, so I return `true` to the initial `ACTION_DOWN` event, until some number of milliseconds has elapsed, at which point I timeout and recognize the gesture as a hold/drag instead of a click.

Once the timeout has elapsed, I'd like to return `false` to further onTouchEvents, so that I can stop receiving events and let the parent view manage the rest of the drag.

However I seem to notice that once you return `true` for the first event, then it receives **all** further events with the associated gesture, even after I continually return `false` to later events. It seems the return value only matters for the very first event, after which it is ignored.

Is there any way to stop receiving `onTouchEvent`, and therefore pass it to the parent, once you have accepted the first event in a gesture?

Answer (score 2):

Remember that the boolean return value of `onTouchEvent` only indicates whether the event has been handled or not - you should still receive events when the user is in the middle of a gesture.

Generally, you can tailor the behavior however you want in your handler:

```
private boolean hasHandledGesture = false;

public boolean onTouchEvent( MotionEvent event ){

    if( !hasHandledGesture ){
        // Do your actual handling here for the first event
        return true;
    } else {
        return super.onTouchEvent( event );
    }
}
```

However, I think in your case you'd be better off creating a handler that registers via [setOnLongClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnLongClickListener%28android.view.View.OnLongClickListener%29).  Not only will it make your life easier, but you'll also let the OS decide how long it takes to make a long press.  This is the best choice if you want to make the length of the press match the rest of the system, helping the overall app's native look and feel.

If you want to catch some more complex events, you might want to look at using a [GestureDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html), but it probably is more complexity than you need if you're just detecting a long press.

Comment: Deleted my first comment, I originally misread your answer. I'll look into the longClickListener, though I think your code sample there might not help. If I return false or call super.onTouchEvent after returning true the first time, then the parent view never sees the rest of the gesture, even if I return false from the original onTouchEvent.

Comment: @Tim - In that case, the GestureDetector might be exactly what you need. If you pass the event along to the detector before all of your custom handling, you should be able to leave your existing handlers alone and just receive a callback when the long press is triggered.

Comment: Sure, I'll look into the GestureDetector.